# Cent OS 7 File System recognize expanded root

Tags: linux, hard-drive, drive, expansion

I have expanded the disk for / - and it is MOSTLY recognized.
For example - Applications / Utilities / Disks sees all 84GB, but Applications / Utilities / Disk Useage Analyzer only sees the old 49GB.  So, some things know that "/" has been expanded, some don't.  (See screenshots)

How to get EVERYTHING access to the space?

[Disks_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy92o.png) - Sees all 84 GB

[DUA_SS_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gTCH.png) - Sees all 84 GB

[DUA_SS_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sy7C.png) - Doesn't see the expanded space?

Answer (score 1):

You expanded your filesystem correctly. The "49GB" you are concerned about is the space currently used on the filesystem by files under `/`, not the total space.

Comment: Not sure how to feel about that answer - this means I have other issues that might be harder to find... LOL!